# Calculating the partial derivative of a 3D vector array

Tags: python

I have 3D vector data in the following form

```
[x, y, z, Q]
```

Where `x, y, z` is the Cartesian coordinates of the points and  `Q = [u, v, w]` is the vector coordinates at these points. I would like to calculate the partial derivatives of this vector data with respect to x, y and z in Python. What is the Pythonic way to achieve this?

Here's my code which prepares some raw data,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
u, v, w = [], [], []
xp, yp, zp = [], [], []
Q_vec = []
cords = []

for i in range (0, len(x)):
    for j in range(0, len(x)):
        for k in range(0, len(x)):
            x0, y0, z0 = x[i], x[j], x[k]
            u0 = np.sin(np.pi * x0) * np.cos(np.pi * y0) * np.cos(np.pi * z0)
            v0 = -np.cos(np.pi * x0) * np.sin(np.pi * y0) * np.cos(np.pi * z0)
            w0 = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x0) * np.cos(np.pi * y0) *
                  np.sin(np.pi * z0))
            Q0 = [u0, v0, z0]
            cords.append([x0, y0, z0])
            u.append(u0), v.append(v0), w.append(w0)
            Q_vec.append(Q0)
            xp.append(x0), yp.append(y0), zp.append(z0)
```

In this the element i in `Q_vec` is the value of the vector and in cords is the geometrical cordinate of the vector. How can we get the partial derivative of Q_vec with respect to x, y and z ?

Comment: Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your feedback. But is not my question general enough? I just included the toy model as a source for the raw-data. My question is , how can we get the partial derivative in python if we have a 3N vector and their Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest in which direction I should move now? to get a numerical partial derivative from this data?

Comment: I suggest you think about how you would accomplish this task with pen and paper and then attempt to implement the logic in code.  Once you have something coded, come back with specific question.